# Babel and arrow function this is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Am I going nuts? Here is an ES6 Angular controller with an ASYNC web service call. I want to assign the data to `this.tableauEnPreparation` but `this` is undefined inside my arrow function.

Isn't the lexical `this` supposed to be available at this point???

Here is the code:

```
class ListeDemandesController {
  constructor(listeDemandesService, $q, $scope) {
    this.listeDemandesService = listeDemandesService;
    this.$q = $q;
    this.$scope = $scope;

    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {
    this.listeDemandesService
      .getDemandesEnPreparation()
      .then((data) => {
        debugger;
        this.tableauEnPreparation = data;
      });
  }
}

ListeDemandesController.$inject = [
  'listeDemandesService',
  '$q',
  '$scope',
];

export default ListeDemandesController;
```

Isn't the `this` where the `debugger` is supposed to be the scope of the `class`?

The crazy thing is that the data is actually there, and the view updates correctly. But if I do a second or third service call (to a different service), the data is not set to a property on this, and the view doesn't update...

Comment: i had a similar problem last week, i solved it by using `.bind(this)`. Maybe it's a lead to your problem.

Comment: But isn't the whole purpose of arrow functions is NOT to have to bind this?

Comment: What you see in the debugger and what is in the code are not the same thing. Are you actually getting an exception from `this.tableauEnPreparation` saying `this` is undefined, or are you typing `this` into the debugger console? Babel renames variables, so for cases like this, you usually have to write `_this` or `_thisX` where `X` might be some number.

Comment: @loganfsmyth then why, when I put the debugger anywhere and write `this` in the console, does it return me the right result? I am using sourcemaps which should technically allow me to type what I see on screen, and not the transpiled version.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I just double checked in my browser debugger, and it is indeed `this` and not `_this` or other.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Correction, yes, your are right. I was under the impression that the browser was mapping the values entered in the console with the original version of the code (using the sourcemap).

Comment: The more I dig, the more I think the sourcemaps are to blame...

Comment: Sourcemaps can make things like this harder to debug unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. So gulp-sourcemap has an option called `loadMaps`. When is it set to true, it displays the original code in the dev tool, which makes you think you can use the name values as you see... But you were right. By taking a look at the scope box in chrome dev tools, you can see what are the declared variables, and `_this` is actually the one I need to use in the console to get the true value of `this`